# Error: pyramid_gaussian() got an unexpected keyword argument 'multichannel'

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am using code from this [link](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_pyramid.html). Run the program with Python 3.6.5 on Windows 7. My scikit-image version 0.13.1

```
>>> image = data.astronaut()
>>> rows, cols, dim = image.shape    
>>> print (rows, cols, dim)
512 512 3

>>> pyramid = tuple(pyramid_gaussian(image, downscale=2, multichannel=True))
```

`TypeError: pyramid_gaussian() got an unexpected keyword argument 'multichannel'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you are referring to shows an example in the documentation of scikit-image 0.14dev ([documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.pyramid_gaussian)). However, you are using version 0.13.1 and in this version, the parameter multichannel is not available ([documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/api/skimage.transform.html?highlight=pyramid_gaussian#skimage.transform.pyramid_gaussian)).